# how to show a div when scroll bar goes down, and when i scrollbar goes up it should disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a website it like 1800px in height. i want when user scrolldown around 200px it show an div on the top of the layout and its should stick with the page. when user scroll back to top , the div should disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trigger an event on `scroll`:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        topDiv.show();
    } else {
        topDiv.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jquery scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) method

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
      $("span").css("display", "inline").fadeOut("slow"); 
    });
```

Comment: this is just an example, you can add the code you want in the function